# Basic clarifications regarding "$L_\alpha$-definable well-orderings"

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic

So, first a quick re-cap of my own (fragmented) understanding of this, so it would be easier to see what the question is. Firstly let's focus on arithmetic well-orderings. My understanding is that when we say this we have in mind a first-order-formula where the quantifications are intended to be over the $\omega$. So, when we say an arithmetic well-ordering (of $\omega$), we have in mind a formula with two free variables that describes a well-order. Suppose the well-order relation we have in mind is denoted by function $less:\mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. So if we want to know say $less(3,5)$, then we simply put these values $3$ and $5$ in our formula in place of first and second free variables respectively. If the the formula describes a valid well-order then it would return either true or false and we set the value of $less(3,5)$ to be $0$ or $1$ accordingly.Now, as I understand, these are arithmetic well-orderings whose supremum is $\omega_{CK}$.

**(Q1)** Now can we call these well-ordering above "$\omega$-arithmetical well-orderings (of $\omega$)"?

In general, for some $\alpha$, can we call the well-orderings defined by a (first-order) formula, with quantifications assumed to be over $\alpha$, as "$\alpha$-arithmetical well-orderings (of $\alpha)$"? But this doesn't seem enough, since this doesn't account for parameters? So how do we account for these in transition from $\omega$ to $\alpha$? Do we allow, in our formulas, arbitrary ordinals less than $\alpha$ as "constants"? It seems that we would have to add similar provision for the notions below too?

**(Q2)** What would "$L_\alpha$-definable well-orderings (of $\alpha$)" mean? My guess is that means something similar to above except that quantifications are assumed to be over $L_\alpha$ (instead of simply an ordinal). Is this correct or is there some other meaning of the phrase.

**(Q3)** How do we account for parameters in the question from (Q1) to (Q2). Is it similar to how I tried to describe in (Q1)? And similarly, in (Q2), could we allow any element of $L_\alpha$ as a "constant" in the given formula (defining well-ordering)?

---

As you can see from these questions, I don't have good enough understanding (and intuition) regarding this topic. I am trying to verify that at least whether the meanings of these terms correspond to what I am thinking (and if there is a mistake, it is better to know it).

This question came to my mind few days ago, but I didn't know how to phrase it in a good way. After reading this question on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369529/can-we-pin-down-the-recursively-closed-levels-of-l-by-a-first-order-theory), it seemed to me that I could perhaps phrase it without being too confusing.

Comment: When one talks about $M$-definable configurations for some structure $M$, unless otherwise specified parameters in $M$ are allowed. So "$L_\alpha$ definable well-orderings of $\alpha$" just means "well-orderings of $\alpha$ which are definable-with-parameters in the sense of the structure $L_\alpha$" per the usual conflation of the  $L_\alpha$ with $(L_\alpha,\in)$. So parameters are always folded in. The only remaining issue is whether we're taking as our ambient structure $\alpha$ or $L_\alpha$, but it's pretty clear it should be the latter: very little is definable in $\alpha$ alone.

Comment: In the $\omega$-setting, you're implicitly thinking of $\omega$ as $(\omega;+,\times)$, but for generalizing to higher ordinals what we should really be thinking about is $(L_\omega;\in)$ (which is of course bi-interpretable with $(\omega;+,\times)$. The only reason parameters don't play a role here is that every element of $L_\omega$ is actually definable without parameters already, so they're unnecessary, but that stops being the case higher up.

Comment: Basically, you never actually want to use $\alpha$ as your ambient structure, it's just far too weak. You can, however, use $\alpha$ as your *parameter set* when working in $L_\alpha$: in $L_\alpha$ there is a definable bijection between $L_\alpha$ and $\alpha$, so anything definable in $L_\alpha$ with parameters is definable in $L_\alpha$ from ordinal parameters.

Comment: Thanks, these are very helpful comments. You are absolutely right when you wrote: "the $\omega$-setting, you're implicitly thinking of $\omega$ as $(\omega; +,×)$". It seems this is one of the reasons why my question is confused. Regarding: "anything definable in $L_\alpha$ with parameters is definable in $L_\alpha$ from ordinal parameters." This was one of the main questions I had in mind (why only ordinal parameters). I haven't quite gotten the reason though.

Comment: It's that parameter-freely-definable bijection between $L_\alpha$ and $\alpha$: you can move parameters along that. This is just a general model-theoretic fact: if $M$ is any structure, $X\subseteq M$, and $F:M\rightarrow X$ is a bijection which is parameter-freely definable in $M$, then everything definable with parameters from $M$ is definable with parameters from $X$. In our case $F$ is the bijection coming from the usual $L$-ordering.

Comment: In hindsight, my question is really confused. That's because when I talked about $\omega$-arithmetic and tried to generalize it to $\alpha$-arithmetic (even allowing parameters here), I totally forgot that the correct analogy would be to use $<$ relation instead of $+$,$\times$ in case of $\omega$. I almost feel like deleting the question (but may be the comments would be helpful for some other people too). But I am curious, what if we keep the $+$,$\times$,$<$ in definition of $\alpha$-definable. I suppose this would have to be very well studied.

Comment: I've turned my comments into an answer, let me know if it can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's talk about the ambient structure issue: do we work in $\alpha$ or $L_\alpha$ (or more precisely, the structure $(\alpha;\in)$ or the structure $(L_\alpha;\in)$)?

The answer is resoundingly the **latter**: indeed, very little is definable over $\alpha$ at all. This may seem to clash with our intuitive picture of "arithmetic = definable over $\omega$," but this is because we're thinking of $\omega$ in two different ways here. When doing classical computability theory we can get away with thinking of "$\omega$" as shorthand for $(\omega;+,\times)$, but for generalizing to higher ordinals what we should really be thinking about is $(L_\omega;\in)$ (note that this is of course bi-interpretable with $(\omega;+,\times)$). The point is that while $\omega$ has a "natural" arithmetic on it which gives us the complexity we expect, a general ordinal doesn't, and the right structure to build "around" an ordinal to let us compute with it properly is the $L$-hierarchy up to its level.

Now on to parameters. Parameters may seem like a new feature which arises when we go to higher $\alpha$, but that's not really fair; rather, they're just *unnecessary* when $\alpha=\omega$ since every element of $L_\omega$ is actually definable without parameters already; this stops being the case for $\alpha>\omega$ in general ([except sometimes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597)). And parameters from the ambient structure *are* allowed here - in general, when one talks about $M$-definable configurations for some structure $M$, unless otherwise specified parameters in $M$ are allowed.

So "$L_\alpha$-definable well-ordering of (a subset of) $\alpha$" just means "A well-ordering of (a subset of) $\alpha$ which is definable-with-parameters in $L_\alpha$." There is, however, a nice simplifying feature worth mentioning: there is a definable-without-parameters bijection $F:L_\alpha\rightarrow \alpha$ (coming from the usual $L$-ordering). Via this we can switch between well-orderings of $\alpha$ and well-orderings of $L_\alpha$, and switch between parameters from $\alpha$ and parameters from $L_\alpha$, without impacting the definitions. In particular:

> For every well-ordering $W$ of some subset of $L_\alpha$ which is definable in $L_\alpha$ with parameters from $L_\alpha$, there is a well-ordering $R$ of some subset of $\alpha$ which is definable in $L_\alpha$ with parameters from $\alpha$.

This is just an example of a more general model-theoretic fact (which I'll phrase very informally but should be reasonably clear nonetheless):

> Suppose $M$ is a structure, $A,B,C,D$ are parameter-freely-definable subsets of $M$, and there are parameter-freely-definable bijections $F:A\rightarrow B$ and $G: C\rightarrow D$. Then every configuration $X$ on $A$ defined with parameters from $C$ is equivalent to the configuration on $B$ defined with parameters from $D$: we first show that $X$ itself can be defined using parameters from $D$ instead of $C$ by considering $G^{-1}$, and then move $X$ from $A$ onto $B$ via $F$.

In our case "configuration on" means "well-ordering of a subset of," $F$ and $G$ are both the bijections $L_\alpha\rightarrow\alpha$ coming from the $L$-ordering, and equivalence is isomorphism.

Comment: "$L_\alpha$-definable well-ordering of (a subset of) $\alpha$". I have a question about this. If we are talking about a well-ordering on $\alpha$, the formula (for some well-ordering on $\alpha$) will give a true/false for every pair $x_1,x_2 \in \alpha$. But the formulas also gives a true/false whenever, say, $x_1 \in L_\alpha-\alpha$ or $x_2 \in L_\alpha-\alpha$. We just "dont care" these?

Comment: @SSequence Yup, that's right. And keep in mind that $\alpha$ is a parameter-freely-definable subset of $L_\alpha$, so there's nothing weird going on: we have a *pair of* formulas $\varphi(x)$ and $\psi(y,z)$ where $\varphi$ defines the domain of the ordering and $\psi$ describes the ordering on that domain.

Comment: Nevermind, I deleted the later comments. I think I will probably ask a question about that some time later perhaps. The main question I asked has been answered.

Comment: Though, thinking about it since yesterday, I think I have gotten a very basic level idea about this. So, from a logical perspective, the easier way to generalize from $\omega$-arithmetic to $\alpha$-arithmetic (which I presume is synonomous with $L_\alpha$-definable) is to think in terms of iterated definability. That way definable from $L_\omega$ is supposed to correspond exactly with $\omega$-arithmetic (as described in first paragraph of question from example). In general, all sets definable over $L_\alpha$ gives us $L_{\alpha+1}$. Finally, $\alpha$-recursive sets arise  *[continued]*

Comment: from this in the form of $\Sigma_1(L_\alpha)$ definable. I am definitely unclear about the more (detailed) relation between $\alpha$-arithmetic and $\alpha$-recursive, but at least this gives a basic idea. Please do let me know if there is a significant mistake in this and previous comment.